# How do I ignore warnings, but keep error messages from 'find'

Tags: bash, find, symlink

I'm trying to run a `find` command, and due to the way the folder is set up, I keep getting the following warnings several times in my script:

```
find -L ./server/ -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | <rest of really long complicated script>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
find: File system loop detected; ‘./server/~andreas/root’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘./’.
find: File system loop detected; ‘./server/~bob/root’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘./’.
find: File system loop detected; ‘./server/~charles/root’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘./’.
...
```

I know **why** I'm getting these messages. Those symbolic links are intentionally placed there for other scripts to use, so I want to safely ignore those warnings in the console output.

How can I prevent `find` from displaying warnings like *"File system loop detected"*, but still keep all "real" error messages?

I can't just tell `find` to ignore every directory named `root`. And find has a `-nowarn` option, but I can't get it to work no matter where I place it. And so far I haven't found a "log level" option for find.

Comment: GNU `find` manual about `-nowarn`: "These warnings apply only to the command line usage, not to any conditions that `find` might encounter when it searches directories". The warnings you want to ignore are of the latter type. This is why you "can't get it to work".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the bash shell, you can use output redirection to suppress specific error messages by filtering stderr through `grep`:

```
find ... 2> >(grep -v "File system loop detected") | ...
```

This is described in the "Process Substitution" section of the bash manual/man pages: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution

Comment: Will this interfere with the output from `&1` that is being sent through the pipe?

Comment: No, because only stderr (file descriptor #2) is being redirected. stdout will still be sent through the pipe as before.